# How can I keep my temperature constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

I'm will start a lab experiment which is about ageing composites.

Main factors of this experiment are temperature and pressure and I'm planning to use a pressure cooker and boil my samples in water.

My question is I'm planning to make my test is 3 different temperature (90°C-110°C-130°C) so how can I keep the temperatures constant? (Pressure can change but I need to keep my temperature constant.)

Comment: Have you asked the lab technicians or your supervisor? How you do it depends on what equipment is available.

Comment: You just need a heating plate with a separate temperature sensor that you can put inside your pressure cooker. This is a pretty standard piece of equipment. You have to work out a way to get the temperature sensor inside the pressure vessel without breaking the pressure seal but this should be easy enough. Typically you'd drill a hole in the pressure cooker and glue the sensor in.

Comment: Yes, this can be an idea but the problem is, because of safety issue I dont think they will allow to drill it. Also Yeah I said pressure can change of course but I also need to maintain some pressure (1.8-2.2 bar) to age the composite and pressure cooker provides it.  So glue a cencor after drill can be risky against pressure because I'll add some water periodicly yeah but it will boil around 20 days. But for heating plate I think it will work and suppose they have it in lab. Thanks for advice.

Comment: You can put it in a pressurized container with water (it will be vaporized if the temperature is higher than 100 degrees C) and heat the container in an oven while keeping its pressure using a pressure relieve valve.